# 'All-in-one' physics undergraduate book?

Tags: resource-recommendations

Are there any books that contain what is usually taught throughout an undergraduate physics degree, in one book, or in volumes? I suppose, it won't contain all information about the many subjects taught, although, you can expect with brevity that the majority of undergraduate modules will be taught, just not to the extent that a single book dedicated to a subject would.

Comment: 10 Volumes of Landau&Lifshitz :)

Comment: I would not advice Landau as a first approach

Comment: Even if you find such a recommendation, I strongly advise you not to take it. First, you benefit enormously from having different perspectives; having one "source of truth" is actually quite limiting and insular. Second, as you hinted in your question, any one source cannot possibly contain all the information you need. Finally, any undergraduate curriculum necessarily makes choices of what to leave out in a lecture. The books always contain complementary (and often more) information that what is presented in a lecture.

Comment: 1. University Physics by Young and Freedman 2. Fundamentals of Physics by Jearl Walker 3. Physics for Scientists and Engineers by Douglas Giancolli